# Receiving error on build after upgrading to Xcode 12.5, regarding registering for notifications (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, push-notification, xcode12.5

After upgrading to Xcode 12.5, my project won't build and I get an error in my AppDelegate. I can confirm there were no problems before upgrade and I can't find documentation to troubleshoot this anywhere. Thank you in advance!

**AppDelegate code:**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import IQKeyboardManagerSwift
import FirebaseMessaging

@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    
    let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        
        IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true
        
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self        
        
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {

          UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

          let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
          UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })

        } else {

          let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
          UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
            
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                         fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
          
          if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {

            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")

          }

          print(userInfo)

          completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)

        }
        
        return true
    }
}
```

**The errors:**

**1)**

```
application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
```

*"Value of type '(UIApplication, [AnyHashable : Any], @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) -> ()' has no member 'registerUserNotificationSettings'"*

**2)**

```
application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

*"Value of type '(UIApplication, [AnyHashable : Any], @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) -> ()' has no member 'registerForRemoteNotifications'"*

Comment: Check your closing } - you seem to be missing at least one before `func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                         fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)`

Comment: @Paulw11 There is no problem with the closures

Comment: Quick update:
I deleted Xcode 12.5 and reinstalled 12.3. The problem is fixed in that older version as I had suspected but I'd like to know what the issue is in 12.5 as I can no longer test the newest iOS